# AssemblyVersion aligned with Appveyor version

Tags: git, github, msbuild, appveyor

I looked for documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Through continuous integration (appveyor), I build at every push (or pull request) on GitHub a project, .NET Class library.

Since every build is tagged with a version, I'd like the assemblies to be versioned with the same version.
Any suggestion?

Do I have to launch MsBuild in a specified way?

I'm trying to understand how to configure the appveyor.yml file to do that, but no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Enable [AssemblyInfo patching](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration#assemblyinfo-patching) in `appveyor.yml`:

```
assembly_info:
  patch: true
  file: AssemblyInfo.*
  assembly_version: "2.2.{build}"
  assembly_file_version: "{version}"
  assembly_informational_version: "{version}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The assemblyInfo patching works well.
I extended that and I am taking the version from the Git Release branch.

You can read it in my Blog post: [GitVersion, Versioning made easy and dry](http://boblokerse.github.io/2015/11/03/GitVersion-versioning-made-easy-and-dry/)